# Optimize MySQL SELECT query with many IF conditionals

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to do this in a shorter or easier way? 
I'm trying to search the brand in the name of the product and display it in a new column. 
It seems a little bit messy:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.code, p.name, p.unit, p.size, 
    IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' apple ')>0, 'Apple', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' western digital ')>0, 'Western Digital', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' kingston ')>0, 'Kingston', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' samsung ')>0, 'Samsung', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' brother ')>0, 'Brother', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' noganet ')>0, 'NogaNet', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' noga ')>0, 'Noganet', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' verbatim ')>0, 'Verbatim', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' logitech ')>0, 'Logitech', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' sandisk ')>0, 'Sandisk', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' infotec ')>0, 'Infotec', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' novatech ')>0, 'Novatech', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' lg ')>0, 'LG', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' epson ')>0, 'Epson', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' genius ')>0, 'Genius', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' hp ')>0, 'HP', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' tp-link ')>0, 'TP-Link', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' tplink ')>0, 'TP-Link', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' nisuta ')>0, 'Nisuta', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' panacom ')>0, 'Panacom', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' sony ')>0, 'Sony', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' philips ')>0, 'Philips', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' toshiba ')>0, 'Toshiba', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' sapphire ')>0, 'Sapphire', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' bangho ')>0, 'Bangho', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' trendnet ')>0, 'Trendnet', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' maxell ')>0, 'Maxell', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' siyoteam ')>0, 'Siyoteam', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' marware ')>0, 'Marware', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' videomate ')>0, 'VideoMate', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' manhattan ')>0, 'Manhattan', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' wd ')>0, 'Western Digital', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' asus ')>0, 'Asus', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' gigabyte ')>0, 'Gigabyte', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' nvidia ')>0, 'nVidia', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' intel ')>0, 'Intel', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' amd ')>0, 'AMD', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' super electric ')>0, 'Super Electric', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' encore ')>0, 'Encore', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' omega ')>0, 'Omega', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' domo ')>0, 'Domo', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' benq ')>0, 'Benq', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' coby ')>0, 'Coby', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' edifier ')>0, 'Edifier', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' kodak ')>0, 'Kodak', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' liteon ')>0, 'Liteon', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' veryjet ')>0, 'VeryJet', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' microsoft ')>0, 'Microsoft', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' asrock ')>0, 'Asrock', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' acer ')>0, 'Acer', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' sharknet ')>0, 'SharkNet', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' airlive ')>0, 'Airlive', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' bags ')>0, 'Bags', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' cooler master ')>0, 'Cooler Master', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' foscam ')>0, 'Foscam', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' eurocase ')>0, 'Eurocase', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' garmin ')>0, 'Garmin', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' kozumi ')>0, 'Kozumi', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' lenovo ')>0, 'Lenovo', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' linksys ')>0, 'Linksys', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' cisco ')>0, 'Cisco', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' d-link ')>0, 'D-Link', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' dlink ')>0, 'D-Link', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' msi ')>0, 'MSI', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),'  ')>0, '', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' pcbox ')>0, 'PcBox', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' sanyo ')>0, 'Sanyo', 
        IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' seagate ')>0, 'Seagate', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' trv ')>0, 'TRV', IF (INSTR(LCASE(p.name),' vitsuba ')>0, 'Vitsuba', 
        '')))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) AS marca,
    p.cost, p.price, p.image,
    p.category_id, c.code AS category_code, c.name AS category_name, 
    p.subcategory_id, s.code AS subcategory_code, s.name AS subcategory_name, 
    p.cf1, p.cf2, p.cf3, p.cf4, p.cf5, p.cf6, 
    w.quantity, s.sales
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
    FROM warehouses_products
    GROUP BY product_id
) AS w ON w.product_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS sales
    FROM sale_items
    GROUP BY product_id
) AS s ON s.product_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id=p.category_id
LEFT JOIN subcategories AS s ON s.id=p.subcategory_id
WHERE p.id!=27
ORDER BY p.id ASC;
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to optimize the query. You should redesign your table so that the brand name is a column, or a foreign key to a `brands` table, not just random text in the name.

Comment: You could simplify it with a `CASE` expression rather than heavily nested `IF`s. But the performance will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You care going to have to have a long list of conditionals.  I think a `case` statement is much more appropriate for what you want to do:

Also, I would use `like` instead of `instr()`.  By default, `like` does not match case, so you can do:

```
(case when p.name like '% apple %' then 'Apple'
      when p.name like '% western digital %' then 'Western Digital'
      . . .
      else ''
 end) as marca
```

You still have to go through the same list of comparisons, so the code will be very long.

If performance is not a particularly big issue, but maintaining the code is, you might want to have a table with the search string and full name.  A typical row would look like:

```
SEARCHSTRING    FULLNAME
'% apple %'     'Apple'
```

You could then find *all* matches by doing:

```
select p.name, group_concat(ss.fullname separator ', ') as fullnames
from products p left outer join
     searchstrings ss
     on p.name like ss.searchstring
group by p.name;
```

Then you can just add new rows to this table to search for additional products.

EDIT:

If you want one row per match for the second suggestion, you can do:

```
select p.name, ss.fullname
from products p left outer join
     searchstrings ss
     on p.name like ss.searchstring;
```

Comment: I'm using the second suggestion. However, if I use group_concat, I get only 1 row with all the "fullnames" separated by a comma. If I don't I get duplicated rows if more than one match is made.

Comment: @matiq . . . I figured you wanted one row per `p.name`.  The query is simpler (and I just edited it in) if you want multiple rows.  Note:  this uses `left outer join`, so all `p.name` would have at least one row.  If you want only matches, change it to just a `join` (or equivalently `inner join`).